# How do I parse through '<Amazon::Ecs::Response:0x000001069911d0>' in amazon's API response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Amazon's API and search for a book using the following code and the amazon ecs gem which is part of my Ruby on Rails application:

```
Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :AWS_access_key_id => 'myaccesskeyid',       
  :AWS_secret_key => 'mysecretkey'
}


res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('ruby')
puts res
```

In the terminal I think I am getting a response because I end up getting back:

```
<Amazon::Ecs::Response:0x000001069911d0>
```

How do I access the data or parse through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) you can check that your response object doesn't have any errors and check the total results using:

```
res.has_error?            # return true if there is an error
res.total_results         # return total results
```

Assuming that you're response object is OK, you can traverse through each item and pull out the data you are interested in. Eg:

```
res.items.each do |item|
  # retrieve string value using XML path
  item.get('ASIN')
  item.get('ItemAttributes/Title')
end
```

Not sure if you have tried this already but looks like a good place to start.

Comment: Huge help! For some reason my array is empty? And I tried changing the keyword in the item search, any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: when I change it to 'res.has_error?' I get true as a return boolean value, so I"m guessing there is a mistake somewhere? If so, how can I debug that?

Comment: If you try `res.error` it should return the error message(s) allowing you to debug any problems

Comment: I'm getting 'HTTP Response: 403 Forbidden' when I fixed everything. What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden likely means that you're not correctly sending through your AWS access key and secret key.

Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :AWS_access_key_id => 'myaccesskeyid',
  :AWS_secret_key => 'mysecretkey'
}

'myaccesskeyid' and 'mysecretkey" should be alphanumerics that you receive from AWS